# I get "src="[object Object]"" on <img> when i load image with React.lazy on my web app

Tags: reactjs

I just started learning React JS to do my first web app and I have this problem: When I do a React.lazy function on my const Image, not image loading.

I have search and I don't have any idea why this isn't working. If you can help me please. :/

```
import React, { Suspense } from 'react';
import '../style/App.css';

function App() {

    const Image = React.lazy(() => import('../img/macbook.png'));

  return (
    <Suspense fallback={<div>Chargement...</div>}>
        <header>
            <div className="container">
                <div className="items-left">
                    <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
                    <div>Lorem ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum </div>
                    <button>Se connecter</button>
                    <button>En savoir plus</button>
                </div>
                <div className="items-right">
                    <img src={Image} height="10px" width="10" alt=""/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
        <footer>

        </footer>
    </Suspense>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I import Suspense from React like on the doc. I do a const where I execute the React.lazy function with the import and the directory of my image.

I search on lot of forum but nothing work (probably because I don't understand).
Put the function on my function App() {...}.
Copy and paste the documentation example and integrate with what i want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React.lazy() is for loading react components, to lazy [load](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/loading) images add the `loading="lazy"` attribute to your img

```js
<img src='../img/macbook.png' height="10px" width="10" alt="" loading="lazy"/>
```

Comment: Ooooh ok thanks you ! I think this is not working.